# for function calls, what is the best/correct way to display an error message with 'line no.' & 'src file name' in it?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I've been wondering, when a function is called and the arguments did not meet the requirements,
what is the best or correct way to display the error message with 'line no.' & 'src file name' in it?

you see for over a month now what I'm doing is I use a macro to achieve this behaviour.

so I have a source code where I will call a function

```cpp
    // main.cpp

    #include <iostream>
    #include "somefunc.hpp"

    int main()
    {
        int a = 1, b = 2, c = 5, d = 5, e = 1;

        somefunction(c,d);
        somefunction(d,c);
        somefunction(a,b);
        somefunction(a,e);

        return 0;
    }
```

this is the function and below it is a macro definition that passes `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` onto the function along with the arguments

```cpp
// somefunc.hpp

#ifndef SOMEFUNCTION_HPP
#define SOMEFUNCTION_HPP

#include <iostream>

void some_function_raw(size_t LINE, const char* FILE, int arg1, int arg2)
{
    if(arg1==arg2)
    {
        std::cout<<"GOOD\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::string errmsg = "function call on line "+std::to_string(LINE)+", in file "+std::string(FILE)+
                            " arguments not equal ("+std::to_string(arg1)+"!="+std::to_string(arg2)+")\n";
        throw std::logic_error(errmsg);
    }
}
#define somefunction(int_arg1,int_arg2) some_function_raw(__LINE__,__FILE__,int_arg1,int_arg2)

#endif
```

and when I run this program it will show at what file where the error occur and at what line

output

```
    GOOD
    GOOD
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
    what():  function call on 'line 10', in file 'main.cpp' arguments not equal (1!=2)

    Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't know if this technique is acceptable, or maybe this is bad, so I've been
wondering is there a much better way or a correct way to achieve this?

Comment: In C++20 there's [source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) which lets you access this through genuine functions instead of preprocessor macros.

Comment: I know of no way for a function to infer the location from which is was called and would wind up right about where you are. But because I hate macros, I'd replace `somefunction` the macro with a function and trust the compiler to inline it. I would also consider hiding `some_function_raw` inside an anonymous namespace to prevent misuse.